# How to setup static page with css in subdirectory in rails public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano

I'm trying to setup jekyll blog in my public/blog directory.

For this question let say I just want to have `public/blog` directory with `index.html` and `css/site.css` with css for this page.

I'm deploying it using capistrano, so I added `public/blog` to `linked_dirs`

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

css/site.css:

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Now after `cap production deploy` I can visit `domain.com/blog` and see `Hello World` header, but it does not load css file.

I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` error.

Do you know how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It was more a nginx question.

I added this to my site nginx file:

```
  location ^~ /blog/css/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```